# Show the values in the grid using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I m trying to generate heatmaps for the some data and my code is shown below:

```
data = [['basis', 2007, 2008],
        [1, 2.2, 3.4],
        [2, 0, -2.2],
        [3, -4.1, -2.5],
        [4, -5.8, 1.2],
        [5, -5.4, -3.6],
        [6, 1.4, -5.9]]

x_header = data[0][1:]
y_header = [i for i in range(1, 13)]
data=data[1:]
for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i] = data[i][1:]
arr = np.array(data)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#heatmap = plt.pcolor(arr, cmap = 'RdBu')
norm = MidpointNormalize(midpoint=0)
im = ax.imshow(data, norm=norm, cmap=plt.cm.seismic, interpolation='none')

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(arr.shape[1]), minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(arr.shape[0]), minor=False)
ax.xaxis.tick_top()
ax.set_xticklabels(x_header, rotation=90)
ax.set_yticklabels(y_header)

fig.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

It generates the image

[image]

I also want to show values inside the grid.  Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Sure, just do something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random((4, 4))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# Using matshow here just because it sets the ticks up nicely. imshow is faster.
ax.matshow(data, cmap='seismic')

for (i, j), z in np.ndenumerate(data):
    ax.text(j, i, '{:0.1f}'.format(z), ha='center', va='center')

plt.show()
```

[image]

However, the labels are hard to see, so you might want a box around them:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random((4, 4))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# Using matshow here just because it sets the ticks up nicely. imshow is faster.
ax.matshow(data, cmap='seismic')

for (i, j), z in np.ndenumerate(data):
    ax.text(j, i, '{:0.1f}'.format(z), ha='center', va='center',
            bbox=dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='white', edgecolor='0.3'))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Also, in many cases, `ax.annotate` is more useful that `ax.text`. It's much more flexible in how you can position text, but it's also more complex.  Have a look at the examples here: http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html

Comment: Just for the records you should be able to also use `ax.table` to achieve a similar result.

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano can you create an answer for using tables?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `ax` you can simply:

```py
plt.matshow(data)

for (x, y), value in np.ndenumerate(data):
    plt.text(x, y, f"{value:.2f}", va="center", ha="center")
```