# How to print (visualize) a nd numpy array as a 2d matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a nd numpy array that emulates an 2d matrix in which each element is a column vector. I need to print the 2d array as it were a matrix.

Here is the code that creates the array:

```
Lx = 4
Ly = 4
f = 3
q = 10
pop = np.random.randint(q, size = (Lx, Ly, 1, f))
```

And the array looks like this:

[[[[3 3 6]]

[[5 2 2]]

[[6 0 2]]

[[5 8 8]]]

[[[7 8 2]]...

I need to see it as somehow this:

```
print(pop[0,0][0], pop[0,1][0], pop[0,2][0], pop[0,3][0])
print(pop[1,0][0], pop[1,1][0], pop[1,2][0], pop[1,3][0])
print(pop[2,0][0], pop[2,1][0], pop[2,2][0], pop[2,3][0])
print(pop[3,0][0], pop[3,1][0], pop[3,2][0], pop[3,3][0])
```

[2 9 2] [5 5 8] [4 9 3] [4 2 3]

[3 9 0] [6 4 0] [8 3 9] [6 4 1]

[4 8 9] [2 2 6] [1 3 8] [4 5 6]

[4 1 5] [8 0 9] [3 9 7] [4 4 3]

I can't use the print method of the example because the array can be much more larger.
Ideally, it would be amazing to visualize it as in the image in this example:

[Visualize 1D numpy array as 2D array with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58332372/visualize-1d-numpy-array-as-2d-array-with-matplotlib)

Thanks for all advice!

Comment: If the Q&A you linked to answers your question, why did you ask it?

Comment: Hello @wwii I really don't think that the example in the link answers my question, i use it because the image is very related to what I need.

Comment: Did you try nested for loops to iterate over the first two dimensions?

Comment: @wwii I'll try that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested four loop with the *empty* dimension removed:

```
In [46]: z = pop.reshape(tuple(d for d in pop.shape if d > 1))

In [47]: z.shape
Out[47]: (4, 4, 3)

In [48]: for x in z:
    ...:     for y in x:
    ...:         print(y, end=' ')
    ...:     print()
    ...:     
[4 0 3] [0 5 6] [7 4 2] [9 2 6] 
[8 3 1] [0 8 8] [5 7 9] [3 1 5] 
[4 9 9] [4 8 5] [0 8 7] [8 9 7] 
[8 7 4] [4 7 5] [1 8 5] [4 3 0]
```

Or (using the same `z`):

```
In [55]: n = z.shape[1]

In [56]: fmt = '{} ' * n

In [57]: for x in z:
    ...:     print(fmt.format(*x))
    ...:     
[4 0 3] [0 5 6] [7 4 2] [9 2 6] 
[8 3 1] [0 8 8] [5 7 9] [3 1 5] 
[4 9 9] [4 8 5] [0 8 7] [8 9 7] 
[8 7 4] [4 7 5] [1 8 5] [4 3 0]
```

Comment: do you think that it is possible to print the elements as column vectors? I tried to transpose `.T` each one but does not work.

Comment: You could adapt my second example with matplotlib and specify the *print* direction of the text.