# Plot Array as Grid with values in Python

Tags: python

I need to plot an array. I tried the code from Joe Kington ([Show the values in the grid using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998083/show-the-values-in-the-grid-using-matplotlib)), but I get the error:

```
for (i, j), z in np.ndenumerate(array):

#ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2).
```

Can someone please help me find the mistake?

This is the code I tried:

```
with rasterio.open("C:/Users/...raster.tif") as data:
    array = data.read()
  
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.matshow(array, cmap='Greens')
    ax.axis('off')
    for (i, j), z in np.ndenumerate(array):
        ax.text(j, i, '{:0.1f}'.format(z), ha='center', va='center')

    fig = plt.gcf()
    plt.savefig("C:/Users/...grid.jpeg")
    plt.close(fig)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

array = np.array([[[0.953, 0.938, 0.938],
[0.959, 0.951, 0.944],
[0.977, 0.976, 0.973]]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.matshow(array, cmap='Greens')
ax.axis('off')
for (i, j), z in np.ndenumerate(array[0]):
    ax.text(j, i, '{:0.1f}'.format(z), ha='center', va='center')

fig = plt.gcf()
```

or squeeze the first dimension of your array: `array = array.squeeze(axis=0)`, before using it in your `for` loop.

Comment: Thats it! I had a 3d array, with the "array.squeeze(axis=0)" it works fine. Thank you : )

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the linked question
[Show the values in the grid using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998083/show-the-values-in-the-grid-using-matplotlib)
it has given a 2D array as *grid* input (2 brackets at begin and end):

```py
data = [['basis', 2007, 2008],
        [1, 2.2, 3.4],
        [2, 0, -2.2],
        [3, -4.1, -2.5],
        [4, -5.8, 1.2],
        [5, -5.4, -3.6],
        [6, 1.4, -5.9]]
```

Yours is **3-dimensional** (3 brackets at begin and end) and syntactical malformed, **without commas** separating each element:

```py
[[[0.953 0.938 0.938]
[0.959 0.951 0.944]
[0.977 0.976 0.973]]]
```

Maybe you can adjust your input right away or transform it as [suggested by Alone Together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69703819/5730279) using NumPy's [`squeeze`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html).